Github Fork Button Loads Page But Doesn't Make A Fork Repo
I click the green fork button on a public github repository. This shows a loading bar on the Github website, but instead of showing a copy of the repo on my personal github page, the page loads the public repository and there is no fork. There is no error message. The fork function was working before.
Expected result: The repo is forked and there's a copy in my github repository.

Sounds like a question for github support. I'm not sure this is really on-topic here.

Create a ticket with important details: developer console (errors, warnings, info), network tab screenshot, browser and operating system. https://support.github.com/request

After asking some others, I found that Github had flagged my account as a bot or related. There was no error message on the page about account status when pressing the fork button. If others have this problem with the fork button or function I recommend they check their account settings and account activity on Github.
